# Laravel orderBy highest points

Tags: php, laravel

Check this code below:

```
$scores2 = Highscore::all()->orderBy('points', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

I have this code, but when I load the page it won't get the highest score of each player. I don't know what I did wrong can somebody help me out please?

Comment: remove `all()->`

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove `->all()` since you are receiving the data through the `->get()` method:

```
Highscore::orderBy('points', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries) explains it really well.

Answer (score 0):

`::all()` is static for `->get()`
So if you want to make static method right after class use `query()`
like

```
$scores2 = Highscore::query()->orderBy('points', 'desc')->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

and can format more pretty

```
$scores2 = Highscore::query()
    ->orderBy('points', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: because you are using group by, it is not related to current question. Create another one with question about right SQL